# AccessViolationException during application exit while using MassTransit with Kafka and in-memory bus

Tags: masstransit, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I'm using version 7.1.4 of MassTransit with .Net Core 3.1, ASP.NET Core Web Application. It happens when I close the application by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. When I press stop debugging button, it doesn't occur. The code responsible for registration goes as follows:

```cs
private void ConfigureMassTransit(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(massTransit =>
    {
        massTransit.UsingInMemory((ctx, cfg)
            => cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx, SnakeCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance));

        massTransit.ConfigureRider(
            _kafkaHost, _dbConnectionString);
            });

        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
}

// The rider part.

rider.UsingKafka((ctx, kafka) =>
{
    kafka.Host(kafkaHost);

    kafka.TopicEndpoint<Null, IMessageName>(topicName, GroupIds.PushedDeals, cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CheckpointInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        cfg.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
        cfg.ConfigureSaga<SagaState>(ctx);
    });                
});
```

The exception:

```
Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.NativeMethods.NativeMethods.rd_kafka_consumer_poll(IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.NativeMethods.NativeMethods.rd_kafka_consumer_poll(IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at Confluent.Kafka.Consumer`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Consume(Int32)
   at Confluent.Kafka.Consumer`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Consume(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at MassTransit.KafkaIntegration.Contexts.KafkaConsumerContext`2+<>c__DisplayClass15_0[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].<Consume>b__0()
   at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor+SynchronousFuture`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Run()
   at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor+<RunFromChannel>d__12.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor+<RunFromChannel>d__12, MassTransit, Version=7.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor+<RunFromChannel>d__12, MassTransit, Version=7.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor+<RunFromChannel>d__12, MassTransit, Version=7.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolGlobals+<>c.<.cctor>b__5_0(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Channels.AsyncOperation`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetCompletionAndInvokeContinuation()
   at System.Threading.Channels.AsyncOperation`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SignalCompletion()
   at System.Threading.Channels.SingleConsumerUnboundedChannel`1+UnboundedChannelWriter[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryWrite(System.__Canon)
   at System.Threading.Channels.SingleConsumerUnboundedChannel`1+UnboundedChannelWriter[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].WriteAsync(System.__Canon, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor+<Run>d__11`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor+<Run>d__11`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], MassTransit, Version=7.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa]](<Run>d__11`1<System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Start[[MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor+<Run>d__11`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], MassTransit, Version=7.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa]](<Run>d__11`1<System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor.Run[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at MassTransit.KafkaIntegration.Contexts.KafkaConsumerContext`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Consume(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at MassTransit.KafkaIntegration.Contexts.SharedConsumerContext`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Consume(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
```

When I've commented out topics registration or used RabbitMq as a bus, it has stopped occurring. I know that an in-memory bus is mainly for testing, but there is an existing Kafka infrastructure, so running another infrastructure makes no sense.

Comment: The difference between in-memory vs RabbitMQ is likely just timing. The error appears to be throw by the Confluent client, I'm not sure if it's an issue in their package or the way it's being called.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Do you have any advice on what to do about it?

Comment: No, though your checkpoint interval is insanely low.

Comment: It has been set this way to mitigate Customer Lag.

Comment: I don't see how that makes sense. And the Confluent recommendation is one minute, so...

Comment: This one is happening with docker image locally, isn't it?

Comment: Taking into account Chris answer, you shouldn't commit so often. Your application is spending more time on committing than actual message handling

Comment: @NoNameR According to Docker: yes, it is. Of course Kafka is dockerized, not the application.

Comment: sometime it happens with Docker, I dunno why, previously it was happening even frequently

Comment: Did you already try KafkaFlow instead of MassTransient? I think is more flexible and easier to use :)

Comment: @FilipeFerreiraEsch The solution you suggested doesn't have sagas.